# Flutter - Best way to aggregate data from child widgets in an IndexedStack

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have an IndexedStack in a Scaffold that I use to manage my registration. The Registration widget itself is Stateful, but the widgets that compose it are Stateless. The parent widget looks like this:

```
class Registration extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RegistrationState createState() => _RegistrationState();
}

class _RegistrationState extends State<Registration> {
  int _index = 0;

  void _nextPage() {
    setState(() {
      _index++;
    });
  }

  void _prevPage() {
    setState(() {
      _index--;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: new AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        leading: new IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back,
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
            onPressed: () {
              if (_index == 0) {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              } else {
                _prevPage();
              }
            }),
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      body: IndexedStack(
        children: <Widget>[
          RegistrationPhone(_nextPage),
          RegistrationName(_nextPage),
          RegistrationBirthday(_nextPage),],
        index: _index,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**What is the best way to take data from these child widgets?**

Should I pass in a callback function and hold the data in the parent? Should I pass the information down the line from widget to widget until it's submitted? I don't know what the practices are for sharing data across multiple screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use Provider

Add Dependency :

```
dependencies:
  provider: ^4.3.3
```

here is the Example :

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

/// This is a reimplementation of the default Flutter application using provider + [ChangeNotifier].

void main() {
  runApp(
    /// Providers are above [MyApp] instead of inside it, so that tests
    /// can use [MyApp] while mocking the providers
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Counter()),
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

/// Mix-in [DiagnosticableTreeMixin] to have access to [debugFillProperties] for the devtool
// ignore: prefer_mixin
class Counter with ChangeNotifier, DiagnosticableTreeMixin {
  int _count = 0;

  int get count => _count;

  void increment() {
    _count++;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  /// Makes `Counter` readable inside the devtools by listing all of its properties
  @override
  void debugFillProperties(DiagnosticPropertiesBuilder properties) {
    super.debugFillProperties(properties);
    properties.add(IntProperty('count', count));
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: const <Widget>[
            Text('You have pushed the button this many times:'),

            /// Extracted as a separate widget for performance optimization.
            /// As a separate widget, it will rebuild independently from [MyHomePage].
            ///
            /// This is totally optional (and rarely needed).
            /// Similarly, we could also use [Consumer] or [Selector].
            Count(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        key: const Key('increment_floatingActionButton'),

        /// Calls `context.read` instead of `context.watch` so that it does not rebuild
        /// when [Counter] changes.
        onPressed: () => context.read<Counter>().increment(),
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Count extends StatelessWidget {
  const Count({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(

        /// Calls `context.watch` to make [Count] rebuild when [Counter] changes.
        '${context.watch<Counter>().count}',
        key: const Key('counterState'),
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4);
  }
}
```